# How to send email from a non-gmail account in R

Tags: r

I am developing an application in R and it needs to send the email to specific people in the organization.

```
sender <- "xxxx.yyyy@gmail.com"
recipients <- c("yyyy.xxxx@zzz.com")
send.mail(from = sender,
          to = recipients,
          subject = "Test mail from Rstudio",
          body = "Test email body",
          smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", port = 465, 
                      user.name = "xxxx.yyyy@gmail.com",            
                      passwd = "******", ssl = TRUE),
          authenticate = TRUE,
          send = TRUE)
```

This code works well when the sender sends a mail from gmail account. What can be done to send a email from a non gmail account (Organization email account)? Is it possible?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Did you try it with another Email? What went wrong?

Comment: Yeah. It throws this error message  `EmailException (Java): Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:465`

Comment: `smtp.gmail.com`? Didn't you say you wanted to send an email from a NON-gmail account?

Comment: Yeah. How can we send that?

Comment: the exact same way actually. Just adjust sender, host.name, user.name, port etc to the account you want to use. That's why I asked: What went wrong :-D

Comment: How to find the port and host name for an organization's mail?

Comment: ask your IT I guess..

Answer (score 0):

if your app runs in a linux box, and the mail subsystem is properly configured:

```r
system("echo 'test body' | mail -s 'test subject' -r sender_addr@foo.com dest_addr@bar.com")
```